# Accessing state values inside render() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have built very simple state as follows:

```
state = {
  nested: Array [
    0: {a:'a'},
    1: {a:'a'}, 
    2: {a:'a'},
    3: {a:'a'}...
  ]
}
```

Where `nested` gets values from the remote source (Firebase).

I have tried 3 ways of accessing the a's value of **the last array element**:

1. `Object.values(this.state.nested)[Object.values(this.state.nested).length-1].a`
2. `Object.values(this.state.nested)[Object.values(this.state.nested).length-1]['a']`
3. `Object.values(this.state.nested).map(e=>e.a).pop()`

1st and 2nd methods work all OK in console but give me `undefined` inside React render() method.
And it's all despite the fact that they return nested objects which I've checked by `typeof`.

I can suspect why it is so, but why then the 3rd method is working?
I think there is a reason behind such behaviour but can't imagine of any.

Comment: How/when is the data being fetched from Firebase? Is your component rendering once before the data is fetched?

Comment: It's being fetched inside componentDidMount() lifecycle.

Comment: In that case, the `render()` method will run at least once before the data is fetched. So it will run with whatever state you set initially. You'll probably need an **if** statement to check the state to see if data is actually there.

Comment: @AndyCarlson but what about the 3rd method? All methods work in console, but only the 3rd works inside render() in equal conditions?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely happening because the component is being rendered once before the data is loaded. There are two easy ways to get around this issue:

1. set a default state for the component in the constructor
2. check in the render function to make sure nested has elements

```js
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    //option #1
    state = {
      nested: [{a:'default value'}]
    };
  }
}
```

OR

```js
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      {
        //option #2
        this.state.nested && this.state.nested.length > 0 ? 
        (//return div using the nested information here ) :
        (//return div in the case nested is empty )
      }
    );
  }
}
```

If you are loading the data in the componentDidMount() function, then React will re-render the component once that data is loaded. Be sure to use this.setState() in componentDidMount().

Comment: Thank you for very well detailed answer! But what about the 3rd method? All methods work in console, but only the 3rd works inside render() even though all are in equal conditions. Why is it so?

Comment: @Igniter When you say that it works do you mean that it gives you the data from firebase that you are expecting from the pop() call? Or that it doesn't throw an error in the console?

Comment: I mean if I store the fetched data as a global variable in Chrome console and then play around with it trying to access those values, then I'm able to get the values using all 3 methods. Sorry for confused explanations.